# Question about discontinuous function with directional derivatives at a points

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For a function, if at a point $a$, the function has directional derivatives along some lines, but the function is discontinuous at $a$, does that mean along those lines, the function is continuous, but along some other directions the function is not? What does the graph of such a function look like? Continuous in some direction but discontinuous in others?

Comment: I'm not sure the question is clear. In your first sentence, you say that the function is continuous -- did you actually mean to say *dis*continuous?

Comment: @Allawonder. Yes, should be discontinuous.

Comment: @saulspatz why in every direction? Seems undefined in directions of rational slope?

Comment: @user7530 You're right.  Sloppy thinking. I'll try to fix it.  Trouble is, I'm about to fall asleep.

Comment: @user7530 I deleted the comment.  I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The directional derivative $D_v f$ looks at the restriction of the function to the line in the $v$ direction; it's quite possible for this restriction to be continuous whereas the overall function is discontinuous. An easy example is
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}1, &y \geq 0\\ 0, &y < 0\end{cases}$$
which looks continuous in the $x$ direction, but not in any other direction.

As you may know, existence of directional derivatives is much weaker than differentiability of $f$ (which guarantees that the directional derivative at a point is *linear* as a function of the direction $v$). Perhaps counterintuitively, you can have that the directional derivative of $f$ at a point exists in *all* directions, but $f$ is still not continuous at that point. See [this writeup](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~js/Math202/example2.pdf) for instance which proves that
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}\frac{x^2 y}{x^2+y^4}, & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 0, & x=y=0\end{cases}$$
is such a counterexample (you can create many others of the same family).

Comment: Thanks, I can see the example is discontinuous yet all directional derivative exist, but I can not see what "continuous" along a direction means intuitively, on the graph the discontinuous point is a hole, how can the function "continuous" along a particular direction on a hole?

Comment: @Cathy there shouldn't be a hole (put in the missing point).

Comment: Then what the missing point looks like?